# Length between points on a parametrized compact curve in a metric space

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

Let $\Gamma$ be a continuous compact curve on a metric space ($X,d$) parametrized by $\gamma:[0,1] \to X$.  The length of the whole curve, denoted by $L(0,1)$, can be infinite.  Let $a,b \in [0,1)$.  Is it true that $L(a,b)$ is finite?

Comment: Why would it be finite? The infinite length part can occur anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously not.  For instance, take any curve $\gamma:[0,1/2]\to X$ of infinite length and extend it to a curve $\Gamma:[0,1]\to X$ (e.g., by $\Gamma(t)=\gamma(1/2)$ for all $t>1/2$).  Then the length of $\Gamma$ from $0$ to $1/2$ is the same as the length of $\gamma$ which is infinite.